# Where to find all possible errors in MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, custom-errors, error-list

I want to create a custom error system in MySQLi, for this I will need a list with all error codes and a description on why they are being caused.

I have searched all over the web but can't find anything on [php.net](http://php.net)

---

For example if I create a new object where the host is invalid:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('invalid_host', 'root', '', 'db');
```

then the error code will be `2002` which means it could not find the adress.

The original error looks like:

> php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

But I would want it to display:

> **Connection error!** There was an problem connecting to the database, this is caused by your invalid hostname: "invalid_host" which seems to not be connectable or pingable! (2002)

---

In order to do that I will need to know all the errors that can occure in MySQLi, I haven't found a list yet so I am asking here if you know about a list

---

If you wonder how I'm going to do it I am planning to have an array which will contain of:

```
$error_list = [
    2002 => [
        'category' => 'connection_errors',
        'error_title' => 'Connection error!',
        'error_content' => 'There was an problem connecting to the database, this is caused by your invalid hostname: "invalid_host" which seems to not be connectable or pingable!',
        'error_code' => '2002',
        'error_description' => 'This error is occurred by invalid hostname. Why is this error occurring? It is occurring because you have entered invalid hostname, such as: "msql. example .com"'
    ]

    // And so on
];
```

---

I'd be really happy if anyone know where to find such a list, this project will be shared in the future, and when it's finished I'll add an comment with an link.

---

The project can also make easier and safer (prepared) queries to an MySQL server, with MySQLi.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/error-messages-server.html

Comment: and... https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-client.html

Comment: Shouldn't I be looking for PHP MySQLi @JimL ?

Comment: Those error messages comes from the server. PHP simply just returns them.

Comment: These errors is not the same as the php errors, for example the 2002 in php is `php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known` and the one from dev.mysql.com is `Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '%s' (%d)`.

Comment: You appear to be working under the assumption that a given error code always means the same underlying problem. Or return the same text.  It doesn't.  An even worse example is error 2003.  The code identifies *what failed to occur* (e.g., connecting); it is not always limited to a single *reason* for the failure, and an attempt to reduce it to such will result in giving bad advice.  Arguably, unless you review and account for the entire codebase for mysqli, libmysql, mysqlnd, and anything else in the mix... you can't provide meaningful "expanded" errors.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot you got a point, I'll have that in mind, I can also use the errors already provided but split them to title category and ERROR MESSAGE FROM OBJECT

Comment: As I can see, you are writing a wrapper. I have some interest in writing wrappers, particularly for mysqli, so let me offer you my help and collaboration.

Comment: @YourCommonSense It might be fun working with you. For sure, but for this one I can't do collaboration, this Easy MySQLi class is an experiment on my school, where I picked the subject, if I finish this and get over 50 points I can go to the lines I want to in the future. So it would be awesome, but I can't. I can send you the result of the MySQLi class on mail or something when it's done if you want to have a look and do changes to it.

Answer (score 0):

> But I would want it to display:

You don't want it. Simply because [you're not the sole user of your site](https://phpdelusions.net/programming#reporting_errors).

For a site user, it's still a gibberish. Not to mention that a honest user will be rather bewildered being accused for "providing the invalid hostname"!
If you take *any* mature site, it never shows anything like that. Just a generalized error page says "There is an error, we're already on it".

For a programmer, all this stuff beside the actual error message is just useless rubbish, that litters the actual and useful information. Instead of all that useless stuff, better add a stack trace, the actual SQL query, some critical variables. Again, learn from big boys: good framework will show you not only error message but even the code snippet where the error occurs.

With all the due respect, I understand your idea to improve mysqli. But you have to check your premises first. It is very important to *run* a live site for some time to understand the real purpose of error reporting.

Imagine I'll be in charge for your site after you finish it, and it emits this kind of error. Even if I'd have no idea what does the error message mean, I can google it up. The original error message will give me a 1000 results, while your custom one will give me **nothing**. Please, do not re-tell the error message with your own words - you may lose the important part. Neither should you litter the error message with some useless descriptions. Just leave it alone and make sure that a programmer will read it.